# Converting bank statements to another currency?

Tags: bank-account, financial-statements

I tried googling this. I want my bank statement of my account in State Bank of India, back in India, to show balances in dollars. Google only gives results which show me how to open an NRI State Bank of India account. This is why I want to ask the question here. Hope this is on-topic here.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Umm. Why not ask your bank? How would we possibly be able to help with that?

Comment: If your bank can't help you, all we can suggest is to do the currency conversions yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the account is not dollar-denominated, I would say it does not make sense at all to have dollar-denominated statements. Such a statement would not even be accurate for any reasonable amount of time (since FX rates constantly fluctuate). This would be a nightmare for accounting purposes.

If you really need to know the statements in USD, I think the best practice would be to perform the conversion yourself using Excel or some similar software.